# Semi-circle representation in legend - ArcGIS!

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, legend

I have a little problem that needs solving.
How to represent the legend in ArcMap as in the picture above?

[image: legend]

Or as semi-circle instead of complete circles?

Answer (score 4):

This is called a 'nested' display. After inserting your legend in Layout view, double click the legend to access the legend properties.  Under the 'Items' tab, right-click the item that you would like to modify to a nested appearance, select 'Style', and scroll down until you see a circular symbol with callout lines similar to your example above (right side, middle of the example below). 
[image]

NOTE: This legend option will only appear when the data is being displayed using Graduated or Proportional symbols (more from ESRI: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s500000005000000). You can also change the marker from the default circle to any shape you would like within these menus.

Comment: I never knew that, I'm always learning with GIS SE!

Comment: I've followed the procedure explained, but in the legend item selector there isn't any circular heading only rectangular items.

Comment: Edited my answer to give you a little more direction - see Note above.  Be careful though, some types of data are more suited to this display than others.